# How to remove milliseconds in timestamp spark sql

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

I want to remove the milli seconds part when selecting the column through spark sql.

Ex: 2012-10-17 13:02:50.320

I want the result as 2012-10-17 13:02:50
I tried

```
spark.sql("select cast(datecol as timestamp) from table 
spark.sql("select unix_timestamp(datecol,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") from table
```

Both seems not working, substring works but I need timestamp format ,Is there an other way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your timestamp value is string and you are casting it to timestamp, you can try it using substring function.

Second option :

```
spark.sql("select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(datecol, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') from table")
```

You were not providing the input format, that may be the reason you are getting the error.

I hope, this will work.

Thanks,
Manu

Answer (score 9):

For everyone who is looking for a solution with spark DataFrame methods:
In case your column is of type Timestamp and not String, you can use the `date_trunc("second", column)` function:

```
// remove milliseconds of datetime column
val df2 = df.withColumn("datetime", date_trunc("second", col("datetime")))
```

Answer (score -2):

A way to solve it is to use `to_timestamp` function
if you want to move the values to a new column

```
df = df.withColumn("New Column", to_timestamp("DateTimeCol", 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
```

Comment: This only works if your DateTimeCol is a string representation of the timestamp. It does not work if your DateTimeCol is a timestamp type.